# Exhibiting $f$ such that a vector field $\overline{v} = \nabla f$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

The first is suppose $\overline{v} = (x, 2yz^3, 3y^2z^2)$ and we want to exhibit an $f$ such that $\overline{v} = \nabla f$.  Since $\nabla \times \overline{v}=0$, $f$ exists and we can integrate:

$$\displaystyle  \int f \,dx = \frac{1}{2}x^2+c(y,z), ~ \int f \,dy = y^2z^3+c(x,z), ~ \int f \,dz = y^2z^3+c(y,z)$$

So $\displaystyle f = \frac{1}{2} x+c(y, z) = y^2z^3+c(x,z) = y^2z^3+c(x,z)$. How do you determine $c(x,y), c(y, z), c(x,z)$?

Comment: One interesting, and even very important, question here is: how do we even know $\;\overline v\;$ has a potential function, to begin with?!

Comment: @DonAntonio Because $\nabla \times \overline{v} = 0$?

Comment: $\bar{v}$ has a potential function iff $\nabla \times \bar{v} = (0,0,0)$ for 3D vector fields.

Comment: @Hypthen Exactly: its rotor( or curl) is zero. Nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ f_x = x \implies f = \frac{1}{2}x^2 + g(y,z) $$
We know $f_y = 2yz^3$ so
$$ f_y = 0 + g_y = 2yz^3 \implies g(y, z) = y^2z^3 + h(z) $$
So now we have
$$ f = \frac{1}{2}x^2 + y^2z^3 + h(z) $$
We know $f_z = 3y^2z^2$ so
$$ f_z = 0 + 3yz^2 + h'(z) = 3y^2z^2 \implies h(z) =c, c\in\mathbb{R} $$
And we have that 
$$ f = \frac{1}{2}x^2 + y^2z^3 + c $$

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach: Define $f(x,y,z)=\int_\Gamma \bar v\cdot ds$ where $\Gamma$ is a smooth curve joining the origin to the point $(x,y,z)$. Since you know that this line integral is path independent, you can choose any convenient curve such as the line segment joining these two points. This line segment is conveniently parameterized as $(tx,ty,tz)$, $0\le t\le 1$, giving $$f(x,y,z) = \int_0^1\bar v(tx,ty,tz)\cdot(x,y,z)\,dt = \int_0^1 2x^2t+2y^2z^3t^4+3y^2z^3t^4\,dt = \frac12x^2+y^2z^3.$$ Choosing a different starting point for $\Gamma$ amounts to changing the constant of integration.